# How appear pickerWheel when you touch a textfield in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, textfield, picker

I have a newTextField in my project with Corona SDK, I would like to know if there is a possibility in the normal Corona to click on the textfield and a pickerWheel appears instead of the original keyboard.

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard will always appear when the user taps on a textField. You could add a listener to that textField and manually close the keyboard (but that would also remove the focus of the textField) if you want.

I believe that what you want is for the user to select from a list of possible values (the picker values) and show the selected value in the textField, correct? You would be better served by just using a normal button (widget.newButton) instead of the TextField. Show the picker when the user clicked on that button and update the button label after the user has selected a value from the picker.

Comment: Thanks rsc, I'll do this example.